# Android NDK, Opengl es 2, VBO crashes the render

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

Ok this is the fourth time that I post this issue. It is a complicate problem, I know that.

I'm going to explain all, beacuse I dont know what is important or not, and this problem looks like is something stupid in the code, that I don't realize.

I had been developing a game engine for Android with the render part in c++ NDK, few days ago, I had no problem with this, I could see my game correctly in any android device, then, I wrote more code, updated Android Studio from 1.5.2 to 2.1.3, updated experimental gradle plugin from  0.7.0 to 0.7.3, and all that time I only tested the app on a Nexus 6p with android 6, all was fine, but, oh oh, when I tested it on Android 4, it showed nothing, and when I tested on Android 5, it showed something, but no properly.

Now, I started to debug the app, and I could notice when I draw with VBO the render is broken and nothing is rendered, only the background is showed with the color that I set in `glClearColor`.

So when I draw a triangle without VBO, it is rendered properly, but if I draw the same triangle or even other one with VBO, the render crashes and only shows the background, when I draw a triangle without VBO, and then I draw other one with VBO, I could notice that not matter if I call `glDrawElements`, as soon as the code reach `glBindBuffer`, the renderer crashes.

so thats it, I've already tried:

- go back to Android Studio 1.5.2
- downgrade experimental plugin
- downgrade gradle from  2.14.1 to  2.10
- I've checked all the GLerrors, every single call to gl, and all return 0.
- I've even started to write all the code from scratch (just the c++ code), and I got the
  same result

This is driving me crazy. I wasted 5 days with this, and the more time passes, I feel dumber.

these are my files:

[InterfaceJNI.h](http://code.bulix.org/fglqwy-105839)

[InterfaceJNI.cpp](http://code.bulix.org/mvn3dd-105840)

[OpenGLMng.h](http://code.bulix.org/zq6qqy-105841)

[OpenGLMng.cpp](http://code.bulix.org/585hgn-105842)

[File.h](http://code.bulix.org/rftywd-105843)

[File.cpp](http://code.bulix.org/vjj7l9-105844)

[tmp.h](http://code.bulix.org/xx5ldg-105848)

[tmp.cpp](http://code.bulix.org/4k9lu0-105847)

I hope I can solve this and feel stupid, for so insignificant problem.

I'll appreciate any idea or help, thanks

**EDIT:** maybe the problem is not in the code, maybe is in the gradle settings, or in the manifest, or in the java renderer part, or wherever, but I can not find where

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace? Does it actually crash in `glBindBuffer()`?

Comment: @reto the problem was that the stack trace didn't show me anything, because the app didn't crash, the code kept running, but invalidated all previous entrance

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I solved it. so I found 2 problems:

1. I need to put an explicit `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` to unbind the buffers, I don't know
   why I have to do that, at this stage, because, I didn't need it
   before.
2. `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` seems doesn't exist on android 4, and again, I
   don't know why right now it doesn't exist and few days ago, it did.

So the main problem is solved, but if someone wanted to explain more why is this, it would be great.

Now I'm going to modify every class in my proyect,

Comment: Using `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` for indices is not standard in ES 2.0. It will only work on devices that support the `OES_element_index_uint` extension.