# Correct way to write shaders

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, positioning, vertex-shader

I'm using Opengl es 2 with Android NDK and I have this question.

Why this

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

attribute vec3 position;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {

    gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);
    v_color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

}
```

is different from this?

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

attribute vec3 position;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {

    v_color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);

}
```

with the fragment shader:

```
precision highp float;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
```

the first one sometimes doesn't render anything

Which is the proper way?

Comment: They should produce identical results. Which device/operating system are you testing on? Maybe seeing attribute binding code or fragment shader could also help. Have you called `glGetError`?

Comment: Android 6, after which gl call should I check glError?

Comment: I assume you only intended to ask a question about vertex shaders, but you've actually listed an altogether different problem here. Given the tag [tag:opengl-es-2.0], you should not unconditionally be using `highp` precision for `float` -- support for that is not required in the fragment processing stage of ES 2.0.

Comment: @andon so that would be all the problem?

Comment: No, it's just an assumption you made that is not portable. If you are testing this on the same device and it works sometimes and not others this is not to blame, but if you were to take the same code to some other Android device and find it did not work, the fact that you never checked for `highp` support could be to blame.

Comment: @andon well thank you, it seems you know about this, and I have another big big problem that I haven't could solve, I hope you can help me. [big problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313325/android-ndk-opengl-es-2-vbo-crashes-the-render)